# Se congela un control canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, hilos

Trabajo con Visual Studio 2015, WPF tengo un control Canvas el cual me sirve de lienzo para dibujar un skeleton que lo obtengo scaneando por medio del dispositivo Kinect cuando me pongo frente al dispositivo mi esqueleto que aparece en el canvas se congela.

He intentado por medio de async/await usando task evitar que se congele, este es el código que ocupo.

```
//skeletonCanvas.Children.Clear();
        await Task.Run(() => skeletonCanvas.Children.Clear());
//skeletonCanvas.Children.Add(jointLine);
                    await Task.Run(() => skeletonCanvas.Children.Add(jointLine));
```

Código de todo el evento

```
private async void KSensorSkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        string manoDerecha = string.Empty;
        string manoIzquierda = string.Empty;
        Skeleton[] skeletons;
        using (var frame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
        {
            if (frame == null) return;
            skeletons = new Skeleton[frame.SkeletonArrayLength];
            frame.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletons);
        }

        int iSkeleton = 0;
        var brushes = new Brush[6];
        brushes[0] = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0));
        brushes[1] = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 0));
        brushes[2] = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(64, 255, 255));
        brushes[3] = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 64));
        brushes[4] = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 64, 255));
        brushes[5] = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(128, 128, 255));

        //skeletonCanvas.Children.Clear();
        await Task.Run(() => skeletonCanvas.Children.Clear());
        foreach (var data in skeletons)
        {
            if (SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked == data.TrackingState)
            {
                Joint jointManoDerecha = data.Joints[JointType.HandRight];
                Joint jointManoIzquierda = data.Joints[JointType.HandLeft];

                SkeletonPoint posicionManoDerecha = jointManoDerecha.Position;
                SkeletonPoint posicionManoIzquierda = jointManoIzquierda.Position;

                manoDerecha = string.Format("Mano derecha: X:{0:0.0} Y:{1:0.0} Z{2:0.0}", posicionManoDerecha.X, posicionManoDerecha.Y, 
                    posicionManoDerecha.Z);

                manoIzquierda = string.Format("Mano izquierda: X:{0:0.0} Y:{1:0.0} Z{2:0.0}", posicionManoIzquierda.X, posicionManoIzquierda.Y,
                    posicionManoIzquierda.Z);

                // Dibujar huesos
                Brush brush = brushes[iSkeleton % brushes.Length];
                skeletonCanvas.Children.Add(GetBodySegment(data.Joints, brush, JointType.HipCenter, JointType.Spine, JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.Head));
                skeletonCanvas.Children.Add(GetBodySegment(data.Joints, brush, JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.ShoulderLeft, JointType.ElbowLeft, JointType.WristLeft, JointType.HandLeft));
                skeletonCanvas.Children.Add(GetBodySegment(data.Joints, brush, JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.ShoulderRight, JointType.ElbowRight, JointType.WristRight, JointType.HandRight));
                skeletonCanvas.Children.Add(GetBodySegment(data.Joints, brush, JointType.HipCenter, JointType.HipLeft, JointType.KneeLeft, JointType.AnkleLeft, JointType.FootLeft));
                skeletonCanvas.Children.Add(GetBodySegment(data.Joints, brush, JointType.HipCenter, JointType.HipRight, JointType.KneeRight, JointType.AnkleRight, JointType.FootRight));

                // Dibujar articulaciones
                foreach (Joint joint in data.Joints)
                {
                    Point jointPos = GetDisplayPosition(joint);
                    var jointLine = new Line();
                    jointLine.X1 = jointPos.X - 3;
                    jointLine.X2 = jointLine.X1 + 6;
                    jointLine.Y1 = jointLine.Y2 = jointPos.Y;
                    jointLine.Stroke = _jointColors[joint.JointType];
                    jointLine.StrokeThickness = 6;
                    //skeletonCanvas.Children.Add(jointLine);
                    await Task.Run(() => skeletonCanvas.Children.Add(jointLine));
                }
            }

            iSkeleton++;
        } // para cada esqueleto
        lblManoDerecha.Content = manoDerecha;
        lblManoIzquierda.Content = manoIzquierda;
    }
```

El error que me da es el siguiente:

[image: subproceso propietario es otro subproceso]

> El subproceso que realiza la llamada no puede obtener acceso a este
>   objeto porque el propietario es otro subproceso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La manipulación de controles no se puede hacer desde otro hilo. Esas operaciones deben permanecer en el hilo principal, el UI thread.

El uso de tasks es para efectuar trabajo pesado que toma mucho tiempo, y permitir que este se haga en un hilo distinto para que el UI thread se libere y pueda seguir manejando la interfaz sin que se congele.  Pero este trabajo pesado no debe incluir manipulación de interfaz. Solo puede incluir cosas como llamadas a la base de datos, cálculos pesados, etc..

Para que tu interfaz no se congele, debes identificar qué porciones de tu código, **qué no envuelvan los controles**, toman mucho tiempo, y esos sí puedes usar tasks para liberar el UI thread.

Comment: sstan, el problema que tengo es que cuando me paro frente al dispositivo Kinect mi cuerpo se congela en el control canvas y eso quiero evitar, puede ser en el segundo `ForEach` donde esta comentado Dibujar articulaciones.¿podría ese `Foreach` ejecutarlo en un thread con la técnica que venia aprendiendo?

Comment: Es dificil para mi decir sin poder ejecutar tu código yo mismo y depurar el problema. Pero me suena que no has identificado bien donde el código se está trancando.  Por ejemplo, en tu pregunta anterior, estabas tratando de evitar que una llamada a la base de datos se haga en el hilo prinicipal, lo que tiene mucho sentido. Pero en tu foreach se podía ver que tenías otra llamada a la base de datos, pero no vi que estuvieras preocupado por esa sentencia...

Comment: ... por eso, trata de identificar todas las sentencias que combinadas toman demasiado tiempo, como para congelar la interfaz. Luego, la idea es que restructures tu código para efectuar el trabajo pesado como una primera etapa dentro de un task. Y luego, como segunda etapa, ya fuera del task, usas los datos recogidos en la primera etapa para poner al día tus controles. Pero eso sí, poner al día los controles solo se puede hacer desde el hilo principal, eso es una regla que no puedes violar.

Comment: tenía problema con esa porción de código que solucionamos en la mañana y funciona de maravilla cuando ejecutaba ese código que se conectaba a la DB se me congelaban el canvas y dos Image ayora ya no, ahora solo se congela cuando me para frente al dispositivo y el que se encarga de dibujar en canvas es este evento. Seguiré tu consejo y analizare el código detenidamente.

Comment: Entiendo. Pues en este caso, la técnica de usar otro hilo o task no te va a servir, porque asumiendo que en efecto las operaciones `skeletonCanvas.Children.Clear()` y `skeletonCanvas.Children.Add(jointLine)` son las costosas, estas operaciones deben quedar en el hilo principal. Te tocará ver si no hay una manera mas eficiente de poner al día el canvas que no envuelva remover y agregar todos los elementos. Tal vez haciendo un update mas inteligente donde solo modificas lo estrictamente necesario. Obviamente, digo esto sin entender bien lo que haces, pero espero que esto tenga un cierto sentido.

Comment: el clear es para borrar todos lo skeleton que hubiera en el control y los actualiza con el add pero a la vista del ojo humano es imperceptible es por eso que los movimientos se ven tan naturales, me parece que el trabajo pesado lo hace el primer `Forech` ya que tiene que recuperar todos los skeletons si te puedes fijar en el código es el que hace el trabajo pesado, ¿ese `Foreach` puedo ponerlo en un `Task` así como lo venía haciendo?

Comment: Kinect utiliza cámaras ToF (Time of Fly)para generar una seudo nube de puntos (digo seudo por la baja densidad y la falta de sensibilidad en profundidad de las cámaras ToF).
Cualquier cosa que se te ponga por delante se detectará como un movimiento, por lo tanto voy a tener datos prácticamente siempre.

Comment: Si tenía otra llamada a la base de datos y también aplique la técnica que me enseñaste.